# Запятая перед тире: «Самое мудрое, что создало человечество, — это язык»

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, вторую запятую в предложении: «Самое мудрое, что создало человечество, — это язык».

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Фраза ***что создало человечество*** является придаточным предложением, находящимся внутри главного предложения ***Самое мудрое -- это язык***, поэтому **она выделяется запятыми с двух сторон.**

Answer (score 1):

Здесь запятая закрывает придаточное, т.е. ставится по мотивам иным, чем тире, и поэтому не "поглощается" последним.

Вообще вопрос о взаимозаменяемости и взаимопоглощении тире и запятой при их стечении крайне запутан и грешит противоречивыми формулировками, можете посмотреть по ресурсу, неоднократно поднимался. Но тут случай достаточно простой. Причин сомневаться в необходимости запятой просто нет.